# Stuck in imread function while using android smartphone as camera in Matlab

Tags: android, linux, matlab, android-camera, ip-camera

I have the following situation:

- Windows 10 host
- Linux (Bunsenlabs) on VirtualBox
- Android smartphone connected to PC and can be seen using lsusb
- DroidCam app on smartphone and DroidCam client installed on Linux, adb installed as well.
- Matlab R2017a installed on Linux.

I'm using the following script:

```
url=('http://127.0.0.1:4747/mjpegfeed?640x480');
ri  = imread(url);
fh = image(ri);
while(1)
    ri = imread(url);
    set(fh,'CData',ri);
    drawnow;
end
```

Starting droidcam in Linux I get:

```
Device: Droidcam (v4l2loopback)
Found driver: /dev/video0 (fd:5)
connecting to 127.0.0.1:4747
```

Going in firefox and accessing 127.0.0.1:4747 I can clearly see the video feed from my smartphone.
If I close the tab in firefox (to allow other devices to connect to the stream) and run the script in Matlab, the script would start and get stuck in imread().

More exactly in line 76 from file urlreadwrite.m

```
isc.copyStream(inputStream,outputStream);
```

Once I reach there with the debugger, the camera opens on my smartphone (I can see that it also takes the resolution from the url - if I put 10x10, on my smartphone the image would be 10x10) but I can't use the debugger anymore, and no video frame appears in matlab. It looks like it's stuck in an infinite loop and can't pass from that second line.

Does anybody know if this is a normal behavior for this function?
Did I do something wrong in this whole configuration?
Is there any alternative to that function?
Is there a better/easier way to capture video stream in Matlab from my android phone without using wifi, only on usb?